# Index Corruption in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, fluentcassandra

The Select all query works fine in a Cassandra KeySpace-Column Family. 
But when the Select by Key query is issued for a specific key, the FluentCassandra client throws a timeout exception.
This happens for some of the keys in the same column family , while others succeed.

Could this be due to an index issue.

Comment: can you update your question with example codes stating your problem

Comment: You should check your cassandra logs for any errors.  If there aren't any most likely the timeout is because your query is reading too much data to return in the 10 second timeout.

Comment: I'm falling into the same issue. Looking into the logs I've found that Cassandra tries to look for a data file that doesn't exists (Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/MyApp/MyColumn/QualCanal-MyColumn-hf-6659-Data.db (No such file or directory)) . Fummy that files ending with 6685 and 6686 exists there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I provided no further information about your issue. But since I had the same issue and stumbled upon this question here is what happened to me.

I followed @Richard suggestion and took a look on cassandra logs while the query was executed. I turned out that some non existent data file was being referenced.

Restarting Cassasandra forced the system to check its logs and rebuild the data files solving the issue.